# Is context.getSystemService() an expensive call?

Tags: android, android-context

Is `context.getSystemService()` an expensive call?

I.e. I have build a little http networking library (I know there are other http networking libraries available) that uses `ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);` to check (before executing a http request) if the user is connected with the internet (kind of fail fast strategy).

My question is should I save the `ConnectivityManager` as an instance variable (class field) of my http library or should I call  `ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);` every time before I start an http request to retrieve a "new" ConnectivityManager? Is the same ConnectivityManager instance returned every time I call `getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)` (in other words, can storing a ConnectivityManger into a class field lead to problems since my http library is a long living one --> lives as long as application run)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My question is should I save the ConnectivityManager as an instance variable (class field) of my http library or should I call ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); every time before I start an http request to retrieve a "new" ConnectivityManager?

I would hold onto the instance. While `getSystemService()` does not in practice seem to be that expensive to call, why call it more often than needed?

> in other words, can storing a ConnectivityManger into a class field lead to problems since my http library is a long living one --> lives as long as application run

To be on the safe side, call `getSystemService()` on the `Application` singleton (`getApplicationContext()`). *Usually*, the object returned by `getSystemService()` knows nothing about the `Context` that created it. Occasionally, it does — `CameraManager` in Android 5.0 suffered from this flaw, though that was fixed in Android 5.1. If the system service object is going to outlive the context that I am in, I tend to use `getApplicationContext()` to retrieve the system service, out of paranoia.

<sub>(the memory leaks, they're out to get me!)</sub>

> Is the same ConnectivityManager instance returned every time I call getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)

To be honest, I have never looked.

Comment: Your paranoia is well-founded - other system services hold on to the context from `getSystemService`. `WindowManager` is the one I'm familiar with - and even though you can get a window manager with the application context, it then behaves differently (and since it holds the context, yes, it will leak your context, too).